# timedatectl or dpkg-reconfigure tzdata in 16.04

Tags: dpkg, time, systemd, timezone

I've been using the following script to set Ubuntu 14.04 servers to UTC timezone:

```
echo "Etc/UTC" > /etc/timezone
dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
echo UTC=yes >> /etc/default/rcS
```

Now, in 16.04 it seems that I can configure everything with `timedatectl`. Now my script looks like:

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 0
timedatectl set-ntp 1
timedatectl set-timezone UTC
```

1. Is that is this correct? Is it setting up any server to use UTC timezone both as local time and on RTC?
2. Is there anything missing from not running `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

Comment: Ubuntu uses UTC by default. It's Windows that uses local time.

Comment: I want to make sure that my servers are configured to the same values, no matter what 'default' was being used by a VPS provider. Thus I cannot believe in any default and have to set it myself.