# what's the difference between timedatectl and dpkg-reconfigure for setting the timezone?

Tags: dpkg, time, timezone

I found 2 possible ways to set the timezone on my Ubuntu Server.

**Using timedatectl**

```
timedatectl set-timezone CET
```

**Using dpkg-reconfigure**

```
echo "Etc/CET" > /etc/timezone
dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

Is there a difference between these methods? If yes, what is the difference?

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800085/timedatectl-or-dpkg-reconfigure-tzdata-in-16-04), but it's not quite the same thing I'm looking for. I want to know the difference between these 2 methods so that I know what I'm doing.

Is it possible that the 2nd method is no longer working on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 2):

timedatectl was introduce by systemd and is related to the init system

*so if you try this command in devuan it will not work because devuan is a team who decide to reject systemd.*

the dpkg way will work on any system supporting .deb because it is related to the packaging system.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer, but I found myself asking the same question today, so I did some research that I would like to share with you:

The `timedatectl` program is part of `systemd` and therefore available on most modern Linux distributions, including the latest Ubuntus.

If you know your timezone, like `America/New_York` or `Europe/Berlin` you can easily set your local time with your mentioned "fire and forget" command and be done with it, which makes it attractive for automation like in system-setup-scripts:

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone <timezone>
```

If you don't know your timezone you can print out its list of all avaiable timezones via

```
timedatectl list-timezones
```

The command `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` is used to reconfigure the *tzdata* package, which also contains timezone data. Running the command will bring up a dialog box that allows you to select the geographic region and city representing your timezone, so you would **not need** to know or find your timezone in advance.

This method is older and has been used for many years to set the timezone in Debian and Ubuntu so this method may not work on some newer versions of Ubuntu as it may have gotten or may get replaced by `timedatectl`.

To summarize: they both do the same, one is newer than the other and may be available or not if you are still handling old systems. So it is good to know both of them. I prefer `timedatectl` when provisioning systems because it is just a one-liner that I can put in a script because I know my region beforehand, versus manually going through the list of timezones in `tzdata` with my arrow key, which may come in handy if you don't know your timezone and want to narrow it down.

As of Mar'23 both still are available in Debian 11 (bullseye) or even testing (sid/bookworm).